# Progress bar based on elapsed time in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to add a progress bar based on elapsed time in Python2.7. Basically, I am executing a bash script from python that takes about 90 minutes to complete, but the underlying application being called doesn't provide information that often. There are about 45 minutes where the user wouldn't see anything happening and I don't want them to kill the script thinking the process has frozen. Because I know approximately how long the executable takes to finish, I want to add a progress bar based on the elapsed time. Here is what I have so far:

```
    def sys_call(self, cmd, log_file="prog.log"):
        # setup toolbar and start timer
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        stdo = sys.stdout
        msg = "elapsed {}".format(datetime.timedelta())
        stdo.write(msg)
        stdo.write("\b"*len(msg)) # go to beginning of line
        stdo.flush() # flush buffer

        # initiate command and monitor
        log = open(log_file, 'w')
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''): 
            log.write(line.decode('utf-8'))

            # display toolbar
            msg = "elapsed {}".format(datetime.datetime.now() - start)
            stdo.write(msg)
            stdo.write("\b"*len(msg)) # go to beginning of line
            stdo.flush() # flush buffer

        log.close()
```

I am looking for a way to update the progress in the terminal based on the elapsed time. The `line` loop above stops looping for long periods of time after the script is executed because the application stops sending anything to `stdout`, so my elapsed time stops updating which is misleading. I can take care of calculating and printing a percentage for the user to see the process is not frozen, but I'm not sure how to run the elapsed time code in a separate thread.

I looked into `progressbar` and `tqdm`, but unfortunately, I cannot use third-party packages due to requirements outside my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the blow snippet [from this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/)

```
# Python program killing
# threads using stop
# flag
  
import threading
import time
  
def run(stop):
    while True:
        print('thread running')
        if stop():
                break
                  
def main():
        stop_threads = False
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = run, args =(lambda : stop_threads, ))
        t1.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        stop_threads = True
        t1.join()
        print('thread killed')
main()
```

Ultimately, here is what I came up with:

````
import datetime
import time

    def thread_progressbar(self, stop):
        """Progress Bar Thread

        This function is to be used with `threading`. Reference example.
        Note, ensure the thread is a daemon otherwise CTRL+C will not
        work and if this occurs, you will have to kill the thread from
        the command line even though `main()` has already terminated.

        Example
        ```
        thread_stop = False
        t = threading.Thread(target=thread_progressbar, args=(lambda:thread_stop,))
        t.daemon = True # make daemon to kill thread if main terminates
        t.start() # start executing thread
        <do something else>
        thread_stop = True # break out of inf loop
        t.join() # kill thread
        ```
        """
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        while True:
            # get elapsed time and stay at 99 if we exceed expected time
            elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start
            percent = int(100.0*(elapsed.total_seconds()/self.expect_time.total_seconds()))
            percent = 99 if percent >= 100 else percent

            # display toolbar
            sys.stdout.write("[{}%](elapsed {})".format(percent, elapsed))
            sys.stdout.write("\b"*len(msg)) # go to beginning of line
            sys.stdout.flush() # flush buffer

            # use stop to determine when we are done
            if stop():
                elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start
                sys.stdout.write("[100%](elapsed {})\n".format(elapsed))
                break
            time.sleep(1)
````

Answer (score -1):

Use '\r' to move cursor back to beginning of the line after every time you print the bar, and just loop the bar until the task is done making sure to have  '\r' at the end of every iteration.
This is an example of how that would be used

```
import time
for x in range(101):
  print(f'{x}% done',end='\r')
  time.sleep(1)
```